# foreach is iterating only the last entry of my array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to load my table using knockout foreach binding, it can read how many items are inside my array but the looped data is just the last entry inside my array.

To picture my issue, instead of (sample only):

```html
<td> 1st </td>
<td> 2nd </td>
<td> 3rd </td>
```

It outputs:

```html
<td> 3rd </td>
<td> 3rd </td>
<td> 3rd </td>
```

This is my view:

```html
<table id="clientsTable" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 10px; text-align:center">#</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Member Date</th>
            <th>Mobile No</th>
            <th>Alternate Mobile No</th>
            <th style="width: 70px">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: clientsList">
        <tr>
            <td> <strong data-bind='text: clientID'></strong></td>
            <td> <span data-bind="text: fullName"> </span></td>
            <td> <span data-bind="text: locationID"> </span></td>
            <td> <span data-bind="text: address"> </span></td>
            <td> <span data-bind="text: memberDate"> </span></td>
            <td> <span data-bind="text: mobileNo"> </span></td>
            <td> <span data-bind="text: mobileNoAlternate"> </span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is the script part:

```
var clientLine = function (cid, lid, fname, lname, mname, fullname, fullname2, memdate, address, mobileno, mobilenoalt, cpid) {
    self.clientID = ko.observable(cid),
    self.locationID = ko.observable(lid),
    self.firstName = ko.observable(fname),
    self.lastName = ko.observable(lname),
    self.middleName = ko.observable(mname),
    self.fullName = ko.observable(fullname),
    self.fullName2 = ko.observable(fullname2),
    self.memberDate = ko.observable(memdate),
    self.address = ko.observable(address),
    self.mobileNo = ko.observable(mobileno),
    self.mobileNoAlternate = ko.observable(mobilenoalt)
};

function Clients(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.clientsList = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function (client) {
        return new clientLine(client.ClientID, client.LocationID, client.FirstName, client.LastName, client.MiddleName, client.FullName, client.FullName2, client.MemberDate, client.Address, client.MobileNo, client.MobileNoAlternate)
    }));
};

var viewModel = new Clients(@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)));
$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

My view receives and convert my model and I can see that it correctly converts my model into json array. If anyone could pin point the cause of my problem that would really help me and be much appreciated.

Comment: `self` isn't defined in `clientLine`. perhaps you should use `this`?

Comment: Jeez. that was it. :) So simple mistake, thank you my hero! Please add this as an answer so I can select it. Im happy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't declare `self` in `clientLine` so its going to the global scope.

Either

- declare `self` in `clientLine`
- use `this` instead.

Comment: I need 8mins to accept. Thank you for fast answer! God bless!

Comment: @super-user np anytime!